# Very Basic Ito's Formula Problem

Tags: calculus, derivatives, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $(X_t)_{t≥0}$ be an Ito process of the form $dX_t = µ(t)dt + σ(t)dW_t$ for some $µ ∈ \mathbb{L}^1(0, T)$ and $σ ∈ \mathbb{L}^2(0, T)$. I have been asked to apply Ito’s formula to $Y_t = g(t, X_t)$ for $g(t, x) = e^x + t \,sin(x)$ to write $Y_t$ as an Ito process.

So far, I have calculated the partial derivatives: $$g_t = sin(x)$$ $$g_x = e^x + t\,cos(x)$$ $$g_{xx}=e^x - t\, sin(x)$$
And I have plugged these into Ito's formula to give: $$dY_t = sin(X_t)\, dt\, + \, (e^{X_t} + t \, cos(X_t)) \, dX_t \, + \, \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(e^{X_t} \, - \, t\, sin(X_t))\, dt$$

However I am told this is incorrect, and it also needs further steps. Can anyone help guide me in the right direction and inform me where I have went wrong?

EDIT:

I am told that the final solution is as follows:

$$dg(t, X_t) = (sin(X_t) + (e^{X_t} + t\,cos(X_t))\mu(t) + \frac{1}{2}(e^{X_t} - t\,sin(X_t)\sigma^2(t)))\, dt \, + (e^{X_t} + t\,cos(X_t))\sigma(t)\,dW_t$$

Comment: What's the martingale part of $X$ or (differential of) its quadratic variation?

Comment: @AlvinLepik I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Maybe try to write the right hand side in terms of $Y$ (if possible)

Comment: What you wrote is technically right but it is not really done, in that we would usually like to get back to SDE form, which requires substituting in the SDE representation of $dX_t$ and then grouping up all the $dt$ terms.

Comment: @Ian That does it! Thanks

Comment: Technically speaking, an Ito process should be specified by the $dt$ and $dW_t$ terms. So leaving $dX_t$ does not confirm that the process is an Ito process : you have to expand $dX_t$ using what is given and finish it, as others pointed out. I'm just pointing out why the expansion is important :  a proof that $Y_t$ is an Ito process is incomplete without getting $Y_t = ...dt + ...dW_t$ from definition. Without a shred of doubt, however, for this much work I cannot leave without giving you a +1, so there you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The martingale part of $dX_t$ is $dM_t = \sigma (t)dW_t$, which implies  $d\langle M\rangle_t = \sigma(t)^2dt$. So all in all
$$dY_t = g_t(t,X_t)dt + g_x(t,X_t)dX_t + \frac{1}{2}g_{xx}(t,X_t)\sigma(t)^2dt,$$
where $dX_t$ is given. I can't see anything wrong in your end result.

Comment: I have updated the question with the proposed solution, if you can make sense of it

Comment: Use the given $dX_t$ to open parentheses

Comment: Of course! Thank you.